# Graphic Equalizer in Javascript with maximum compatibility

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, html5-audio

I need to make some sort of visualisation for while music is playing through a html5 player, I've been looking at the audio API and found that some parts work only on chrome, some only on firefox.

I'm not that bothered about internet explorer but I need some kind of solution for the other two, does anyone know of a plugin or even some sort of tutorial where I could start? Ideally this would be using javascript, avoiding extra flash applets if possible, Thanks.

Edit:
 Just to clarify, I have MP3/OGA files and I would like to get some kind of visual output while they are playing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out this article: [Visualising  elements with the Web Audio API](http://themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2012/09/18/) (see: [demo](http://themaninblue.com/experiment/webAudioAPI/)).

The [Web Audio API specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) is currently in a draft stage but will eventually become the W3C standard. Firefox currently only supports the incompatible, Mozilla-specific [Audio Data API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Audio_Data_API), but it is marked as "deprecated" in favor of the Web Audio API. Unfortunately work has not yet started on the new Web Audio API in Firefox. The Bugzilla [bug 779297](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779297) was created to track progress on implementing this standard.

**TL;DR** You cannot get audio visualizations working cross-browser [without Flash](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html) at the moment. The Web Audio API is the future.

Comment: Guess it's all a waiting game until HTML5 release day then, thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath for "HTML5 release day". The editor of the HTML Working Group, Ian Hickson, has already given a [timeline for HTML5](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/title/718). The final proposed recommendation will be released until **2022**.

Comment: Sure, but with browsers wanting to keep up, I'd at least expect them to have something working by the 2015 draft release